# WiFi hotspots are bypassing Cloudfare DNS Android App 1.1.1.1 when activated on phone

Tags: dns, android

Have Cloudfare DNS Android App 1.1.1.1 activated on phone. Use on the phone https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ to see your dns. It says Cloudfare.

Create a hotspot on phone. Access the hotspot from laptop. Check the https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ from the laptop. Now the DNS reported being used is not Cloudfare's anymore. Its the ISP of the phone provider.

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer the phone isn't used as proxy so your computer can use any DNS server you want.

Comment: The DNS is taken from hotspot